# How to monitor the blockchain for new blocks

Tags: transactions, blockchain, block, ruby

I want to scan new transactions as they are added to the block chain.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do this. Are there any APIs that allow for this? Or is there a way to directly tap into the bitcoin network with ruby?

Comment: I’d recommend https://blockchainwebhooks.com or https://blockcypher.com for handling this - I’ve used both services, they’ve both been stable and reliable. Blockchain WebHooks is much more affordable if you need to scale

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure, I'm [BlockCypher's](http://www.blockcypher.com/) Developer Advocate. We have both a WebSockets/WebHooks API for unconfirmed transactions, which you can read about here, along with a Ruby example: http://dev.blockcypher.com/?ruby#using-webhooks .

But if you wanted to run a local implementation that's primarily Ruby-based, you could try Coinbase's Toshi, or bitcoin-ruby:

- https://github.com/coinbase/toshi
- https://github.com/lian/bitcoin-ruby

Answer (score 0):

You should starting by running Bitcoin Core, the reference client for the bitcoin network. Then you will find a ton of libraries (including Ruby) that can work with that to let you see new transactions, blocks, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are looking for is websocket API. There are several APIs for this, but the most popular are blockchain.info and chain.com.

Here's a simple javascript implementation I made with chain.com websocket:  http://jsfiddle.net/93vrLet3/1/

If you want to learn more, here's a step-by-step video and written tutorial on the subject: http://btcthreads.com/display-real-time-bitcoin-transactions-with-jquery-and-websocket/